# How to prove: Every affine set can be expressed as the solution set of a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

How can I prove that every affine set can be expressed as the solution set of a system of linear equations?

Please note that set $C  \subseteq \textbf{R}^n$ is said to be affine if for any $x_1 , x_2 \in C$ and $\theta \in \textbf{R}$, we have $\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2 \in C$.

Comment: What is your definition of an affine set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix an element $x_0 \in C$.

**Claim:** The set $K = \{x-x_0: x \in C\}$ is a *linear subspace* of $\Bbb R^n$.

**Claim:** There exists a linear map $T$ whose kernel is precisely $K$.

**Claim:** $C$ is the solution to the linear system $Tx = Tx_0$ on $x$.

Comment: thanks @omnomnomnom. But I really don't know how to prove the second section "There exists a linear map $T$ whose kernel is precisely $K$." ?!

Comment: It depends what you can assume.  Worst case, here's the full outline: begin with a basis $v_1,\dots,v_k$ of $K$, extend this to a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$. We can define the map $T$ by 
$$
T(a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n) = a_{k+1}v_{k+1} + \cdots + a_{n}v_n
$$